# Core Reporting API v4, dataTable?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-visualization, google-analytics-api

I was reading the documentation of the core reporting api v4 but couldn't find the output to dataTable option. I prefer this over the JSON output.

How can I output the data as a dataTable (I know it's supported in the v3 version...)?

```
  function queryReports() {
    gapi.client.request({
      path: '/v4/reports:batchGet',
      root: 'https://analyticsreporting.googleapis.com/',
      method: 'POST',
      body: {
        reportRequests: [
          {
            viewId: VIEW_ID,
            dateRanges: [
              {
                startDate: '30daysAgo',
                endDate: 'yesterday'
              }
            ],
            metrics: [
              {
                expression: 'ga:users'
              }
            ],
            dimensions: [
            {
                name: 'ga:date'
            }]                                   
          }
        ]
      }
    }).then(displayResults, console.error.bind(console));
  }

  function displayResults(response) {
    var formattedJson = JSON.stringify(response.result, null, 2);
    document.getElementById('query-output').value = response.result.dataTable;
    <!-- document.getElementById('query-output').value = formattedJson;-->
  }
```

This gives me "undefined"...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Background info for clarity**

The optional output query parameter has been added to the Google Analytics Core reporting API. Is used to select the output format of Analytics data in the response, which is JSON by default. If set to datatable, a dataTable property that contains a Data Table object is included in the response. This object can be used directly with Google Charts. See the [Core Reporting API reference](https://developers.google.com//analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference#output) for details.

**Answer**

The [Google Analytics reporting API v4](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/rest/) does not have the option for exporting data as a data table.

I recommend you add a feature request [analytics-issues](https://code.google.com/p/analytics-issues/issues/list)

Comment: Can't make the tag, need 1500 reputation for it... :/

Comment: What tag do you need to make?

Comment: None, just read your answer wrong haha, wanted to make the analytics-issues tag but it isn't needed :)

Comment: Link this question in your issue.  And link the issue back here I will star it and bring it up with the team next time I chat with them.

Comment: Author posted an issue on the forum https://code.google.com/p/analytics-issues/issues/detail?id=1171

Comment: Thanks for linking my question in the issue! :D